# How to set up content writers to produce articles in their own languages

Tags: i18n-l10n

After spending hours on the Entity Translation and Fields modules I still can't configure a Drupal site, how do I achieve this:

- When a content writer logs in and create a node and drops down to their language, it automatically puts their country prefix in front of it: th/this-is-my-article. Currently it allows the drop down, but when created seems to be in English

Tried this through path auto, doesn't let me add the 'th' bit on

- Translate all nodes automatically - surely I don't have to physically click each node after I've created it to add another language? This cannot be correct?

Any help welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I manage multilanguage sites with [lingotek module](https://www.drupal.org/project/lingotek), but it can be with other modules,to prevent a user to upload a node in a wrong language, with rules module add a rule, event: Drupal is initializing, condition: compare user language with current language, action: page redirect, change language or whatever to prevent it to be in wrong language. once uploaded you can translat it. with lingotek configure your contentype to be auto-translated when uploaded.